# Why "Uniroot" command gives the different results

Tags: r

I have a question on uniroot command. I cannot raise my question in a logical way, because I have no idea about why the outcomes is different each time in the second case of my example bellow.
In the first case the out come is always the same for my f function:

```
library(mvtnorm)
f <- function(y1_upr,y2_upr = -0.05453663,target = 25e-4,df=3) {
    pmvt(upper = c(y1_upr,y2_upr),df = df) - target
}
uniroot(f,c(-10000,10000))$root
```

But I don't know why when I add another argument in the same function, the result changes each time (see bellow):

```
g <- function(y1_upr,
              y2_upr = -0.05453663,
              y3_upr = -0.06236616,
              target = 25e-4,
              df = 3) {
    pmvt(upper = c(y1_upr,y2_upr,y3_upr),df = df) - target
} 
uniroot(g,c(-10000,10000))$root
```

You will see that each time you apply uniroot command with g function, it gives you different result.
Does anyone has an idea on that? Can I find a way to fix my result?

Comment: What is the function `pmvt`?

Comment: The cumlative prob. function of multi-t distribution

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm probably involves some measure of randomness in order to choose a starting point. Try:

```
set.seed(1) 
uniroot(g,c(-10000,10000))$root
```

Comment: +1 The help page details: The methodology is based on randomized quasi Monte Carlo methods and described in Genz and Bretz (1999, 2002).

Answer (score 2):

@joran is correct in that the default `GenzBretz` algorithm of `pmvt` has a random element involved. There is an alternative algorithm, `TVPACK` which gives consistent results, but may be less generally applicable:

```
replicate(10,pmvt(upper=c(0,-0.05453663,-0.06236616),df=3))
 [1] 0.1145384 0.1145367 0.1145365 0.1145336 0.1145381 0.1145354 0.1145385
 [8] 0.1145369 0.1145384 0.1145385
replicate(10,pmvt(upper=c(0,-0.05453663,-0.06236616),df=3,algorithm=TVPACK()))
 [1] 0.1145364 0.1145364 0.1145364 0.1145364 0.1145364 0.1145364 0.1145364
 [8] 0.1145364 0.1145364 0.1145364
```

Comment: Nice.  Can you explain why the results appear deterministic for the 2D case?  Is it just much higher precision, or is it a change of algorithm?

Comment: @BenBolker I'm not sure. Looks like it might be higher precision. The error seems to be roughtly of the order of `.Machine$double.eps` in the 2D case for a range of parameter values